# Add a custom column into wp_posts wordpress db and use wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress

I added a custom column to `wp_posts` and I want to insert data into db by `wp_insert_post` function but it's not like WP default WordPress columns add to the row. Is there any way to edit `wp_insert_post` core function and add some customization to it? Any suggestions to solve my problem?

The code:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $course_title,
    'post_content'  => $course_details,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_category' => array( 8,39 ),
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'sender' => $sender, // this is my custom column and not works ...

);
```

The reference :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Answer (score 0):

I think that your thought is to violate Wordpress terms. We can add the column using SQL. but It's ignored by Wordpress core. 
so If you wanna to add the custom column, we have to use update_meta_data for posts.

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $course_title,
    'post_content'  => $course_details,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_category' => array( 8,39 ),
    'post_type' => 'product',
);
$my_post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
if ($my_post_id) {
    update_post_meta($my_post_id, "sender", $sender);
}
```

if you read the custom column for sender, you can use get_post_meta.

```
if ($my_post_id) {
$sender = get_post_meta($my_post_id, "sender", true);
}
```